# How to save DateTime as Date with TimeZone offset included?

Tags: java, datetime, datetimeoffset, java-6, java.util.date

I have some DateTime including TimeZone Europe/Vienna (+0200). It is fetched by this method:

```
settlementService.getPendingPeriodStart()
```

and look with toString like this:

> 2012-06-01T00:00:00.000+02:00

Now I want to save this date 2012-06-01 as java.util.Date, so I tried something like this:

```
transactionDate = settlementService.getPendingPeriodStart().withTime(0, 0, 0, 0).toDate();
```

But the result is this:

> Thu May 31 22:00:00 UTC 2012

What's the best way to save the DateTime result as Date **including** the TimeZone offset, so transactionDate should be **2012-06-01**. I could tinker with GregorianCalendar, but that's not what I like. This ought to be easier, isn't it?

By the way (if this isn't clear). The local system runs on UTC. That's why the result is **Thu May 31 22:00:00 UTC 2012**.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to save the date with the users timezone, opposed to saving it in a centralized timezone and converting it as appropriate?

Comment: A `Date` cannot have a time zone, so you are really asking the impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. (If you know a better solution, just let me know)

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

DateTime dateTimeWithTimeZone = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Vienna")).withDate(2012, 06, 01).withTime(0, 0, 0, 0);      
Date dateWithTimeZoneIncluded = dateTimeWithTimeZone.toLocalDate().toDate();

System.out.println(dateFormat.format(dateWithTimeZoneIncluded));
```

The result is **2012-06-01** as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11196430/10819573) is misguiding. As a matter of fact,

```
2012-06-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 = 2012-05-31T22:00:00Z
```

The `Z` on the right-hand side is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Writing `2012-06-01T00:00:00.000+02:00` as `2012-06-01`, although a matter of just a function call, is dangerous for any business logic that depends on the timezone because it may have a different date in a timezone with a different offset value e.g. as shown above. `2012-06-01` is just a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/date.html) which should be used to track events like birth date, wedding date etc.

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:

**How to parse the given date-time string:**

The given date-time string has a timezone offset and therefore it should be parsed to `OffsetDateTime`. Since the modern date-time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the date-time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2012-06-01T00:00:00.000+02:00"); // 2012-06-01T00:00+02:00
```

**How to get the date-time out of it in UTC:**

There are multiple ways. The simplest way is to convert it into an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) which represents an instantaneous point on the timeline which is in UTC.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant(); // 2012-05-31T22:00:00Z
```

Alternatively,

```
OffsetDateTime odtUtc = odt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC); // 2012-05-31T22:00Z
```

**How to get `java.util.Date` out of it:**

If at all, you need an instance of `java.util.Date` from the instance of `OffsetDateTime`, you can use [`Date#from(Instant instant)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-).

```
Date date = Date.from(instant); // Thu May 31 23:00:00 BST 2012 <--In my timezone
```

Note that a `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it e.g.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); // 2012-05-31T22:00:00.000Z
```

**How to get the date part out of it:**

As I have already explained, it is dangerous for any business logic that depends on the timezone. However, it's just a matter of a simple function call.

```
LocalDate localDate = odt.toLocalDate(); // 2012-06-01
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A date and the time zone of the user are 2 different things. One is a date, the other is a preference, or a presentation parameter.

Don't try to store them in the same field.

Consider that it wouldn't be even possible to store them together efficiently (without losing precision) as a date can be stored in a long only because it's specified that it's an UTC date.

You can save [the time zone as an offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (a frequent recommendation is to keep the minutes in this offset (`[hh]:[mm]`) because of very small cases).